# I get a contradiction reguarding some operators in HIlbert spaces: where is the problem?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the Hilbert space $X=\mathbb{R}\times L^2[-d,0]$ with norm $|\cdot|$ and consider the bounded linear operator $A \colon X \to X$ defined by
$$Ax=\left [x_0+\int_{-d}^0x_1(\xi)d \xi , -\int_{-r}^\cdot x_1(\xi)d \xi \right ]$$
for every $x=[x_0,x_1] \in X$.

Now consider its adjoint operator $A^*$ which is
$$A^*x=\left [ x_0,x_0-\int_{\cdot}^{0} x_1(\xi) d \xi \right]$$
for every $x=[x_0,x_1] \in X$.

Finally consider $T \colon X \to X$ defined by $Tx=[x_0,0]=T^*x$ for every $x=[x_0,x_1] \in X$.

Now as we have the following inclusion for the ranges $R(T^*) \subset R(A^*)$ by proposition B.1 in [Da Prato, Giuseppe, and Jerzy Zabczyk. Stochastic equations in infinite dimensions. Cambridge university press, 2014] we have for some $C>0$ (independent of $x$)
$$|x_0|=|Tx| \leq C |Ax| $$

But this is in contradiction with the following: consider $|Ax|$, i.e.
$$
|A x|=\left|x_{0}+\int_{-r}^{0} x_{1}(s) d s\right|^{2}+\int_{-r}^{0}\left|-\int_{-r}^{\xi} \eta_{1}(s)\right|^{2} d s
$$
The latter norm does not control $\left|x_{0}\right|.$ Indeed, consider in $X$ the sequence
$$
x^{n}=\left(x_{0}^{n}, x_{1}^{n}\right), \quad x_{0}^{n}=1, x_{1}^{n}=-n \mathbf{1}_{[-1 / n, 0]}(\cdot), \quad n \geq 1
$$
Supposing without loss of generality that $1 / n<r$, we have
$$
|A x^{n}|=0+\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{0}\left|\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\xi} n d s\right|^{2} d \xi=\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{0} n^{2}\left(\xi+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2} d \xi=\frac{1}{3 n} \longrightarrow 0 .
$$
Therefore, we have $|x_{0}^{n}|=1$ and $|A x^{n}| \rightarrow 0$.

Where is the problem? Thanks in advance (Da prato in his book says "we recall some results on linear operator and their images ass they are very important in control theory" letting the reader understand that that is a well-known result).

Comment: $Ax$ should be a pair, consisting of a real number and (an equivalence class of) a function. You defined $X = \mathbb R \times L^2$. Maybe that doesn t solve the problem, but it s the first thing I have noticed.

Comment: Yes sure and indeed it is a pair of a real number and a function. In particular when I write “$\cdot$“ I mean it is a function on $-d,0$

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I missed the comma.

Comment: Yes dont worry. Let me know if you see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range inclusion $R(T^*) \subset R(A^*)$ fails. Indeed, $(1,0)$ is in the range of $T^*$, but every $(x_0,x_1)$ in the range of $A^*$ satisfies $x_1(0) = x_0$ (note that $x_1$ is continuous).